# I dont understand this method error

Tags: java

I am making a ciphering program where user enters a word then a pattern then is will scrabble the word.

here is my error:

```
 1 error found:
  [line: 42]
Error: The method charArray(int) is undefined for the type Cipher
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cipher
{
  public static char cipher (int j){
    char[] cipher1 = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'};
  j = (int) (Math.random() * cipher1.length);//choose a random element from the array
    return cipher1[j];
  }

  public static void main (String[] args){

    System.out.print("Please type a sentence to be encrypted\n");
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = inputScanner.next();
      System.out.print("please enter");
   input = input.toLowerCase();
    int yu = input.length();
    char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();

        int w=1;
    do{
    try{
    w=2;
      System.out.println("please entrer pattern");
      String hello = inputScanner.next();
      int hello2= Integer.parseInt(hello);
      if(hello2<0){
        System.out.println("please enter proper number");
        w=1;
      }
    }catch (NumberFormatException f){
      System.out.println("please enter proper number");
    }

    }while (w==1);

    System.out.print("your encrypted code is ");

    for(int i = 0; i < yu; i++){
    System.out.print(charArray(i)); //THIS IS WHERE ERROR IS HIGHLIGHITNG
    for(int q = 0; q <= w; q++){
    System.out.print( cipher(1));
    }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you created a method called `charArray` anywhere in your code?

Comment: its not a method i used it to send the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be occurring because there isn't a method called `charArray` in your `Cipher` class. I suspect what you really want is to get the elements from an array called `charArray` that you have defined earlier in your code. So the syntax should be `charArray[i]` to get element at index i.

Comment: so switch chararray to cipher (thats my method name)

Comment: I don't follow you. What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: ok shree.pat18 what you said did work but how would i run the program so that if pattern entered is 1 so for every one ltter in the word entered only one added. 


i tried what you said and i entered hello as word
then pattern as 1 but it gave me 4 letters for every 1
HadeEcdbLaebLbagObbg ->HELLO

Comment: And what output did you expect?

Comment: ok

Please type a sentence to be encrypted
HELLO
please enter please enter pattern
1
your encrypted code is HcdbEefaLdafLgdbOfec

and i would want something like this H(random ltter)E(random ltter)L(random ltter)L(random ltter)O(random ltter)

Comment: at the moment it outputs 3 random letters no matter what even i chnage the pattern to 4 or 40. so basicly what ever the pattern number is i would want that many latters to output for each letter

Comment: Declare `hello2` outside the do while loop, and use that instead of `w` in the loop where you call `cipher` method. That will let you call the method as many times as the value of `hello2` which is the pattern value entered by user.

Comment: what do you mean by "and use that instead of w in the loop where you call cipher method."

Comment: Change `for(int q = 0; q <= w; q++)` to `for(int q = 0; q <= hello2; q++)` so your loop is run (`hello2` + 1) times

Comment: um NO IT IS STILL NOT DOING IT
I ENTERED HELLO
PATTERN: 1
AND IT GAVE ME HgeEgcLbeLceOfb

Comment: it is still giving me 2 letters scrammbled even when i entred 1 for pattern

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the method charArray(int) has not been defined here.

When you use are trying to print `charArray[i]` you have accidentally written `charArray(i)`

Instead of accessing the value at position `i` it is trying to execute a method that doesn't exist. Just change `()` brackets to `[]` ones and you will see that your error disappears.

Comment: YES i did that but now i have problem in where the program is running but it outputs 4 scrammbled letters or eevry 1 thats in the user inputed word

Answer (score 0):

when you write it like `charArray(i)` it will try to call a method named `charArray` passing `i` as argument to it(which is not defined actually in your case)

while when you say `charArray[i]` it will understand that you want to access `i`th element of `charArray`

so you need to change

```
System.out.print(charArray(i));
```

to

```
System.out.print(charArray[i]);
```